# Using PHP sessions alongside HTML?

Tags: php, html, session, xhtml, file-extension

I am making a login website where a user can login and the next page will display ("Welcome Username"). I know I have to use Sessions but my question is I have my login and other pages as .HTML (using XHTML) and my database side as .PHP.

Can I have sessions using .PHP and displaying the username on each page on my .HTML files?

If so how would I do this?

Thank You

PS I just started PHP and web development recently :)

Comment: *"Can I have sessions using .PHP and displaying the username on each page on my .HTML files?"* - Only if you've instructed Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP.

Comment: So the only way is either change my .HTML to .PHP or use the .HTACCESS method?